# Bootstrap 3 - How do I make the nav bar sticky on scroll

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I am trying to do is make the nav bar stay at the top of the page when you scroll past it. As I am quite new to JavaScript I looked a few tutorials, however, none of them really worked with the Bootstrap nav bar. I was just wondering if there was a way to do this so that it works with the Bootstrap columns.

Also how could I make it so that while it's scrolling, the background colour starts to fade in?

Here is the HTML code for the nav bar, in case that helps:

```
   <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="mNavbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" id="toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is your nav bar directly at the top of your page? Because maybe you can just use a `position:fixed` nav with no javascript required?

Comment: @Zze It's about 60px below the top of the page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 has a class `.navbar-fixed-top` that can be applied to `nav` element to fixed to top of page. It works with all basic navbar functionality at different screen sizes. There is an example as part of the official [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/).

`<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="mNavbar">`

If you need it to become sticky at a certain amount of px from top of screen then you you'd need to attach a scroll event handler to the page. You would then check the distance the page has been scroll then apply the fixed nav class or set styling to fix to a specific position. Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $navbar = $("#mNavbar");
  
  AdjustHeader(); // Incase the user loads the page from halfway down (or something);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      AdjustHeader();
  });
  
  function AdjustHeader(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
      if (!$navbar.hasClass("navbar-fixed-top")) {
        $navbar.addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
      }
    } else {
      $navbar.removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.navbar{
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="mNavbar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" id="toggle">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what you mean by padding is being added to top and bottom, but you can just override the CSS by adding `.navbar-fixed-top` to your stylesheet after the Bootstrap version and updating the padding values. There could be a `top` CSS value that is moving the navbar away from top of screen, you can resolve that by setting `top` to `0`.

Comment: Good solution unless the nav bar is **not** located at top of screen and they want it to stick once they scroll past it, say halfway down the page or something

Comment: According to the new comment, it's about 60px from top.

Comment: I maybe should have said this is the question. I adapted one of the tutorials, and basically when the window had gone past the top of the navbar, it added the class of `navbar-fixed-top`, however it added padding to the top and bottom. Is there a way to keep the original padding?

Comment: This is the correct answer. However it would be better if this was in a code snippet.

Comment: I added code for detecting scrolling then how to check the scroll position, finally adding/removing the fixed class. You'll need to play around with where you'd want the fixed positioning to start. You may also need to add/remove padding as necessary to meet your specific needs.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Ok, I'll try that out now.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I swapped your existing code to a snippet. You can learn how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ .. Although this is slightly outdated now (especially the UI).

Comment: @Zze For some reason, this code isn't working for me. The class isn't being added to the navbar. Any ideas?

Comment: @name234  I tweaked the code a little bit. The snippet now better displays Alexander's working example. See if this works for you.

Comment: This works but in my case, I only had the content above the nav on screens larger than md (when menu is not collapsed). Since the js code adds and removes the navbar-fixed-top class based on scroll height, it caused my navbar to disappear for a while and come back after the given amount is scrolled on mobiles. I was able to solve it by adding a condition to the "else" statement so it does not remove the class on small screens: "... } else if ($( window ).width() > 767.98) { ..."

Answer (score 0):

to make it scroll down add navbar-fixed-top to your nav tag the catch here is that it will be stuck to the top of the page like so

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="mNavbar">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nyd7sd1q/

Comment: my solution and alexanders are basically the same. if u want it to be fixed but not to the top in your css do #mNavbar{position:fixed!important;}